# What is the Time Complexity of LeetCode 273. Integer to English Words for below code?

Tags: time-complexity

I am confused here what is the time complexity for this ??

StringBuilder insert() has O(n) time Complexity.
I suspect the time Complexity is O(n). But I am not sure. Where n is the number of digits. Link to the question: English words.

```
class Solution {
    public String numberToWords(int num) {
        if (num == 0) return "Zero";
         TreeMap<Integer,String> map =new TreeMap<>();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            
         map.put(0,"Zero");
        map.put(1,"One");
        map.put(2,"Two");
        map.put(3,"Three");
        map.put(4,"Four");
        map.put(5,"Five");
        map.put(6,"Six");
        map.put(7,"Seven");
        map.put(8,"Eight");
        map.put(9,"Nine");
        map.put(10,"Ten");
        map.put(11,"Eleven");
        map.put(12,"Twelve");
        map.put(13,"Thirteen");                                                    
        map.put(14,"Fourteen");                                                             
        map.put(15,"Fifteen");
        map.put(16,"Sixteen");
        map.put(17,"Seventeen");
        map.put(18,"Eighteen");
        map.put(19,"Nineteen");
        map.put(20,"Twenty");
        map.put(30,"Thirty");
        map.put(40,"Forty");
        map.put(50,"Fifty");
        map.put(60,"Sixty");
        map.put(70,"Seventy");
        map.put(80, "Eighty");
        map.put(90,"Ninety");
        map.put(100,"Hundred");
        map.put(1000 , "Thousand");
        map.put(1000000,"Million");
        map.put(1000000000,"Billion");        
            
        while(num >0){
            int key =map.floorKey(num);
            int value = num/key;
            if(key<100){
                sb.append(" ").append(map.get(key));
            }else if(value <100 &&  map.containsKey(value)){
                sb.append(" ").append(map.get(value)).append(" ").append(map.get(key));
            }else{
                sb.append(" ").append(numberToWords(value)).append(" ").append(map.get(key));
            }
            num =num%key;
        }
        return sb.toString().trim();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity is O(log n).

This is because each factor of a billion is divided out of the number with constant time.

The work String Builder has to do is linear in terms of the word that needs to be added, but those word lengths are bounded by a constant, so each `.append` call here has a constant time complexity.

However, speaking here of time complexity feels a bit artificial, as the input is bounded by 2<sup>31</sup>, and time complexity only tells us something about asymptotic behavior. If the input could be arbitrary large (and using a big integer type), then you could generate output like "five billion ten billion four hundred billion three thousand five hundred billion".

But then the thing is that the lengths of the substrings that use "billion" only once is bounded by a constant. Not sure which such substring would be the longest, but it could be something like

"seventeen million seventeen thousand seven hundred seventeen billion seventeen million seventeen thousand seven hundred seventeen".

To make it longer you would need the word "billion" again. And the number of times you will use "billion" is O(logn).

Again, this hypothetical, as the input is bounded, and even the greatest allowed input will only produce a string with one occurrence of "billion", and so we could say it is O(1). But for unbounded input and supporting data type it would be O(logn).